# Is there a way to inject a directive's controller into its link function if that directive uses 'require'?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

If a directive doesn't have the `require` property in the directive definition object set, then the 4th argument passed to `link` is that directive's controller.

If we *do* set `require`, then the 4th property is the controller (or array of controllers) that we `require`, and the directive loses the reference to its own controller. What is the best way to access this?

```
angular.module 'example', []

.directive 'directive1', ->
  restrict: 'E'

  controller: ($log)->
    @sayHi = -> $log.info('hi')

  link: (scope, element, attributes, controller)->
    controller.sayHi() # works.

.directive 'directive2', ->
  restrict: 'A'
  require: 'directive1'
  controller: ($log)->
    @sayBye = -> $log.info('bye')

  link: (scope, element, attributes, controller)->
    controller.sayHi() # works
    # how would I access sayBye?
```

I realise I could put `sayBye` on the `$scope` instead, and access through `scope` in the link function, but is there any way of doing this that *doesn't* involve the scope?

Is this the only way?

```
.directive 'directive2', ->
  ownCtrl = {}

  restrict: 'A'
  require: 'directive1'
  controller: ($log)->
    @sayBye = -> $log.info('bye')
    ownCtrl = this

  link: (scope, element, attributes, controller)->
    controller.sayHi() # works
    ownCtrl.sayBye()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can require an array of controllers including the directive's controller itself. As mentioned in the comments provided in the [**`$compile` documentation**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#comprehensive-directive-api).

```js
angular.module('demo', [])

  .directive('directive1', function() {
    return {
      controller: function() {
        this.sayHello = function(directiveName) {
          console.log(directiveName + ' says hi');
        };
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
        ctrl.sayHello('directive1');
      }
    };
  })

  .directive('directive2', function() {
    return {
      require: ['^directive1', 'directive2'],
      controller: function() {
        this.sayGoodbye = function() {
          console.log('goodbye');
        };
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrls) {
        var d1Ctrl = ctrls[0],
            d2Ctrl = ctrls[1];
        
        d1Ctrl.sayHello('directive2');
        d2Ctrl.sayGoodbye();
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div directive1>
    <div directive2></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I knew about the array, can't believe I didn't try putting the current directive name in it! Thanks for the answer. **PS** never seen the inline runnable snippets in answers either - I like it a lot!